# reader.Read() always get the same value from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm working with C# and ASP.NET Core 7. I'm triying to get the hashed password from my database to verify a login request. The problem is that the value "storedPasswordHash" is always the same no matter the userId is passed.

This method is just for testing and see the passwordhash that is stored with the userid parameter.

```
private byte[] SeePassword(string userid)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Credentials WHERE UserID = @UserID";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userid);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string storedUserID = reader["UserID"].ToString();

                        string storedPasswordHash = reader["PasswordHash"].ToString();
                        string storedPasswordSalt = reader["PasswordSalt"].ToString();

                        connection.Close();
                        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(storedPasswordHash);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    byte[] valor = {0};
                    return valor;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using another method to try the same but with thes userid value, and it works returning the stored ID who is the same to the one given as parameter.

```
private string SeeUserID(string userid)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Credentials WHERE UserID = @UserID";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userid);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string storedUserID = reader["UserID"].ToString();

                        connection.Close();
                        return (storedUserID);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    
                    return "not found";
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm creating the hash using the following method

```
private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using var hmac = new HMACSHA512();
            passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
            passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

        }
```

And Here is where new users are added

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Credential>> Register(CredentialDto request)
        {
            string inputUserId = request.UserId.ToString();
            string inputPassword = request.Password.ToString();
            
            CreatePasswordHash(request.Password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);
            
            credential.UserId = request.UserId;
            credential.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            credential.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

            _dataBaseContext.Database.OpenConnection();
            _dataBaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Credentials ON");
            _dataBaseContext.Credentials.Add(credential);
            _dataBaseContext.SaveChanges();
            _dataBaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Credentials OFF");
            _dataBaseContext.Database.CloseConnection();
     
            return Ok(credential);

        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you define `commandP`? It's not defined in either of the supplied methods, so is it a property of the containing class instead of the local `SqlCommand` instance?

Comment: Aside... [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: I'm editing the question, was a mistake writing the question. It should be just command

Comment: Aside... `SqlCommand` is also a class that implements `IDisposable` so it needs to be managed by a `using` block as well.

Comment: So when you set a breakpoint and step through the method, what do you see happening?

Comment: @stuartd at the end it alwasy respond with "U3lzdGVtLkJ5dGVbXQ==", during the method it shows "System.Byte[]"

Comment: Is it possible that all of the records you've tried actually have the same hash in the database table? i.e.: could there have been an `update` statement without a `where` clause that's affected all rows?

Comment: `U3lzdGVtLkJ5dGVbXQ==` is base64 encoded data. Have you considered that you might want to use `System.FromBase64String(storedPasswordHash)` to return the decoded bytes instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(storedPasswordHash)`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I do not think so, there's actually no update, and the hash are different in the SSMS

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(storedPasswordHash)` to pass from  string to byte,but i don't understand when is passing to base 64

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Credentials ON/OFF`? Why??? That is a huge code smell. You should never ever do that from application code. You can only have `IDENTITY_INSERT` in effect for a single table in a database at a time and it will break concurrency.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Oh, I actually don't know.  I'm kinda new and I remember seeing that in another question as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Just look at Credentials in the database to get PasswordHash values. I guess they are all the same.

P. S.
It seems you need to modify:

```
            credential = new Credential() { UserId = request.UserId,
                PasswordHash = passwordHash,
                PasswordSalt = passwordSalt
            };
```

Comment: I'm creating the hash using another method, I'll upload it in the question. Could it be possible that it is creating the same hash for all the users and passwords?

Comment: Code fragments you provided are not enough to verify the whole chain. Pls. provide how you add/update a user in Credentials.

Comment: You wrote "the hash are different in the SSMS" and "Could it be possible that it is creating the same hash for all the users and passwords?" at same time. They counteract each other.

Comment: thanks, I just upload the method that add new users to the db

Answer (score 0):

your code is behaving exactly in accordance with the flow of design ASP.NET Core  Identity and password hashing

when using what your code is trying to do as a unit test for user credential encapsulation, that failure to extract the password becomes a false positive

put another way, why hash the password if you have a use case to view sensitive user detail, you could just violate identity credential storage standards by using plain text or plain encryption methods

this link should help come to terms with your code design and context for your text
https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/
it does say
*"A hash is a one way function, so given the password you can work out the hash, but given the hash you can't get the original password back. For security reasons, the characteristics of the hash function are important; in particular, the hash function should be relatively costly to compute, so that if your database of password hashes were to be compromised, it would take a long time to crack them"*

Comment: "When it comes to logging in, users POST their username and password to the app. The app will take the identifier and attempt to find an existing account in its database. If it finds the account, it retrieves the stored password hash associated with the account. https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-asp-net-core-identity-passwordhasher/ 

The app then hashes the password that was submitted, and compares the two hashes. If the hashes match, then the password is correct, and the user can be authenticated. If the hashes don't match, the user provided the wrong password, and should be rejected"